# Div content doesn't load on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So I'm trying to load a page that is in same folder as my main page, and it doesn't load on click. Maybe something is wrong with my code. I know that it is called because I checked it with alert.

Code bellow.

```
<script>
    function closeIt() {
            e.preventDefault();
             $("#load-here").load($(this).attr('secound.html'));
    };
</script>

<div id="buttons" > 
                <form>
                <button class="btn" onClick="closeIt()" >secound</button>
                 </form>
            </div>

<div id="load-here">
     hehehe
    </div>
```

Comment: You have a function called `closeIt` that loads content trough ajax? And what is `$(this).attr('secound.html')` supposed to do? (http://api.jquery.com/attr/)

Comment: im not using ajax ;/ maybe i should use ajax?

Comment: you are using ajax, load is basically just a shorthand. I was actually referring to the poor name choice, you are not closing anything...

Comment: okay buttons was in <form> tag im noob ! Now i left on 3 divs that ill show hide;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple of problems here. First, your function `closeIt` is not a jQuery event handler, so `e` hasn't been defined and you can't call `preventDefault()` on it. Secondly, you are misusing `attr`, which is used to get an attribute from a DOM element. Replace the function definition of `closeIt` with the following:

```
function closeIt() {
    $("#load-here").load('secound.html');
}
```